# Can GPU support and test shader code of an older version?

Tags: opengl, glsl, version, shader

Say I want to test shader code of an older version, which is GLSL 1.2.
The GPU on the machine actually can support GLSL 4.0 (from the hardware specification).

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but... if the GLSL compiler is relatively standards compliant it should at least _warn_ you if you write say `#version 120` and try to use something that's not supposed to exist in 1.20.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman, I mean right now my GPU can work for higher version of shader. If I input a lower version of shader, can it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to run shaders for a lower version.

Just make sure to identify the glsl version the code is written against in the very first line of every shader source, e.g. `#version 120`

The OpenGL context should also use the compatibility profile, the core profile does not contain deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an OpenGL context in compatibility mode, which probably is the default.